# Why there is square between two columns while reading a csv file in R

Tags: r, csv

Why is there a square between two columns while reading a csv file in R?

https://easyupload.io/wi9dn9

```
df<- read.csv2("Book1.csv")
```

[image]

Comment: Did you look at your source data (using notepad, not Excel). Are there strange characters in it? Maybe include the first two lines of that source data in your question as well.

Comment: We may be able to help you if you upload the CSV file somewhere.

Comment: https://easyupload.io/wi9dn9